# How to check configured mappings while debugging

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using Automapper v3.2 in a project. I am getting an exception

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
```

However I am creating the map in a class like this:

```
internal class MyTypeProfile: Profile
{
    public MyTypeProfile()
    {
        var map = CreateMap<FromType, Data.Ef.Models.ToType>();
        map.ForMember(d => d.Id, s => s.Ignore());
    }
}
```

I don't know how to investigate this - is it possible to check at run-time which mappings are configured? If I attach a debugger what would I look for to see what mappings are configured?

Comment: There is a feature ([Configuration Validation](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html)) to validate the configured maps, but this will not help in your case (missing map). Are you adding your profile? `Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.AddProfile<MyTypeProfile>(); });`. Also, the inner exception should tell you which mapping is missing ("Mapping types: FromType -> Data.Ef.Models.ToType").

Comment: Which .NET Framework version are you using?

Comment: dotnet core 2.0